# 12345.class returning 'Integer' not 'Fixnum' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, integer

On the Ruby tutorials I'm watching when you enter a number with `.class` it returns either `Bignum` or `Fixnum`.

When I do this I get `Integer` instead:

```
12345.class
#=> Integer
```

I'm using irb in the command line on a mac.  Why does the above not return `Fixnum` like it does in the tutorials?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the Ruby version. From Ruby 2.4.0 we have just `Integer`s, no more `Fixnum`s and `Bignum`s distinction

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/

Comment: Note also that in pre-ruby 2.4, the classes `Fixnum` and `Bignum` both **inherited** from the class `Integer`. So, the code: `12345.is_a?(Integer)` will always return `true`, across all ruby versions.

Comment: ...And also, note that in ruby 2.4, to maintain (most) backwards compatibility, `Fixnum == Bignum == Integer`. I.e. `12345.is_a?(Fixnum) #=> true`. But you'll also see warnings like: *"warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated"*. You should remove all references to `Fixnum`/`Bignum` from the code, as they will be removed completely in a future ruby version.

Answer (score -1):

You should get a better tutorial.

Ruby *only* guarantees that a class named `Integer` exists. It *allows* implementation-specific subclasses of `Integer`, and it *mandates* that *if* implementation-specific subclasses *do* exist, then `Integer` *must* be fully abstract, but it does *not* force those implementation-specific subclasses to exist.

I other words:

- `Integer` always exists.
- Implementation-specific subclasses of `Integer` may or may not exist.
- Those implementation-specific subclasses may or may not be named `Bignum` and `Fixnum`.

The tutorial you are using is simply wrong (or at least outdated). This has been officially documented at least since the very first draft of the ISO Ruby Language Specification in 2009, but has been the case even before that.